# How can i use picture as icon in shortcut menu vba access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, popupmenu

I tried this

```
    Set cbCat = CommandBars.Add(conBarName, msoBarPopup, False, False)
 
  Set cbCatCtrl = cbCat.Controls.Add(msocontrolpopup)
  cbCatCtrl.Caption = "Open Form"
 
  Do While Not rsForms.EOF
      Set cbObjectCtrl = cbCatCtrl.Controls.Add()
      With cbObjectCtrl
      
       .Caption = rsForms!Name
       .Tag = rsForms!Name
       .OnAction = "OpenForm"
'      .Picture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture("D:\1.bmp")
```

But it doesn’t work , Error Invalid Picture , I tried .ICO Icons but still the same .
How can I load a picture from my pc and use it as icon instead of faceID method ?
Thanks in Advance
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

I got this from :
[Docs.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarbutton.picture)

It looks like you need to create a IPictureDisp first and then link this to the  relevant control. Also try using a .bmp

```
Sub ChangeButtonImage() 
    Dim picPicture As IPictureDisp 
 
    Set picPicture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture( _ 
        "c:\images\picture.bmp") 
 
    'Here you need to reference your control.  
    With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(msoControlButton) 
        'Change the button image. 
        .Picture = picPicture 
     End With 
End Sub
```

Looking forward to your solution...

Comment: Unfortunately still getting this error

Comment: Hy , i would try changing the file location of the picture, and the name. I would also put the name in a string variable. Furthermore, i would check the picture size. Hope this helps.